# Using Spring Boot without Maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, tomcat, microservices

I am trying to write a simple Java program that displays Hello World as a microservice. I am using Spring Boot, but due to security reasons at my company, I am unable to use Maven. Therefore, I have no option but to download the jar files and add them to my project. I have done so, and made sure I am using the latest jar versions. When I run my program, it shows no errors BUT Tomcat server is not starting and I do not see the "Hello World" message. Below is my code:

```
package com.tutorials;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class HelloWorld {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    //http://localhost:port/

    String hello()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorld.class,args);
        System.out.println("done");


    }



}
```

and below is the output:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)

2020-01-07 11:10:44.563  INFO 13224 --- [           main] com.tutorials.HelloWorld                 : Starting HelloWorld on HQTPM00184606D with PID 13224 (started by z.a in C:\Users\Z\Desktop\Workspace\HelloWorld_Microservice)
2020-01-07 11:10:44.566  INFO 13224 --- [           main] com.tutorials.HelloWorld                 : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-01-07 11:10:44.938  INFO 13224 --- [           main] com.tutorials.HelloWorld                 : Started HelloWorld in 0.703 seconds (JVM running for 1.096)
done
```

and below is the jar files I am using:

[image]

Why Tomcat is not starting and what dependencies I am missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried making `hello()` a public method? You also seem to be missing the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation at class level.

Comment: Side note: "due to security reasons at my company, I am unable to use Maven" -> I would really challenge this as your life will be very hard if you can't use a proper build tool like Maven or Gradle. If they don't want downloads from internet, they can install a company repository like [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/product-nexus-repository) or [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/).

Comment: You really need something like Maven or Gradle to work with Spring Boot. The jar/war it creates has a special packaging and specialized way of starting. Without Maven or Gradle you would need to make sure you also replicate this yourself, else the delivered artifact won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependency tree for spring-boot-starter-web 2.2.2 is:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
|  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
|  |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.29:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.12.1:compile
|  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.12.1:compile
|  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.29:compile
|  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.25:runtime
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.1:compile
|  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.1:compile
|  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.1:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.10.1:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.1:compile
|  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.10.1:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.29:compile
|  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.29:compile
|  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.29:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
|  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
|  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.18.Final:compile
|     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
|     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
\- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
   +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
   +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
   \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
```

But as mentioned in the comments you should try to make the usage of build tools (Maven/Gradle) and a company-wide repository manager (Nexus/Artifactory) possible.